# Сохранить анимацию css

Tags: css, css3, html5, css-animation

```js
  function eCr(Type, atr = {}){
    let element = document.createElement(Type);
    for (var idx in atr)
        idx == 'html' ? (element.innerHTML = atr[idx]) : (idx == 'append' || idx == 'before' ? atr[idx][idx](element) : element.setAttribute(idx, atr[idx]));
    return element;
  }

  let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  c.onclick = e => [1, 2, 3].forEach(() => eCr('li', {html: '<li>texttexttext</li><li>texttexttext</li>', append:ul}));
```

```css
  ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgb(28 28 28 / 90%);
    width: min-content;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 70%);
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: all 2150ms ease-in-out;
  }
```

```html
<div id='c'>КЛИК</div>
<ul>
  <li>Текст</li>
  <li>Текст</li>
</ul>
```

Как сделать, чтобы анимация работала тогда когда добавляем блоки. То есть и на высоту анимация и на ширину, ширина и высота блока относительно дочерних блоков.

Желательно с сохранением свойства transition

Comment: Хелпс, никак не выходит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение с сохранением свойства transition:

1. Добавляем к списку CSS-свойство `box-sizing: border-box`.
2. Перед добавлением элементов устанавливаем свойства `max-width` и `max-height` в значения полной внутренней ширины и высоты (`scrollWidth`, `scrollHeight`).
3. Добавляем элементы в список.
4. Повторяем шаг 2, чтобы актуализировать max-width и max-height и инициировать transition.

```js
c.onclick = e => {
  let ul = document.querySelector('ul');

  ul.style.maxWidth  = ul.scrollWidth  + 'px';
  ul.style.maxHeight = ul.scrollHeight + 'px';

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = 'Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст';
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  ul.style.maxWidth  = ul.scrollWidth  + 'px';
  ul.style.maxHeight = ul.scrollHeight + 'px';
};
```

```css
ul {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(28 28 28 / 90%);
  width: min-content;
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / 70%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">КЛИК</div>
<ul>
  <li>Текст</li>
  <li>Текст</li>
</ul>
```

**UPD**
Код выше работает, если мы добавляем элементы.
Ситуация с удалением сложнее, потому что удаленный элемент сразу исчезает из DOM, и анимировать это не представляется возможным. Т.е. нам нужно зафиксировать текущие размеры (`getComputedStyles()`) свойствами `min-width` и `min-height`, удалить элементы списка, а затем инициировать transition.

Но как мы реализуем transition, если нам неизвестны конечные размеры с уже удаленными элементами? Тут оказался рабочим подход, когда после удаления мы сбрасываем лимиты, получаем размеры, и откатываем состояние. Это происходит достаточно быстро, так что визуально всё происходит гладко.

Таким образом, алгоритм при удалении:

1. Получаем текущие размеры.
2. Сбрасываем inline стили и transition (может еще не закончится анимация после добавления).
3. Фиксируем размеры, задав min-width и min-height (значения от шага 1).
4. Удаляем элементы.
5. Сбрасываем все лимиты, получаем конечные размеры с учетом удаленных элементов, откатываем лимиты.
6. Задаем конечные min-width и min-height, инициируем transition.

```js
add.onclick = e => {
  let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  setMaxLimits(ul);

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = 'Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст';
    li.className = 'added';
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  setMaxLimits(ul);
};

del.onclick = () => {
  let ul = document.querySelector('ul');

  let cw = getComputedStyle(ul).width;
  let ch = getComputedStyle(ul).height;

  // останавливаем transition и сбрасываем inline стили
  ul.setAttribute('style', '');

  // Начальные значения от текущего размера
  ul.style.minWidth = cw;
  ul.style.minHeight = ch;

  // удаляем
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.added')].every(e => e.remove() || true);

  // сбрасываем лимиты, чтобы выяснить размеры после удаления
  ul.classList.toggle('reset');
  let w = ul.offsetWidth;
  let h = ul.offsetHeight;
  ul.classList.toggle('reset');

  void ul.offsetHeight; // хак, чтобы transition сработал

  ul.style.minWidth = w + 'px';
  ul.style.minHeight = h + 'px';
}

function setMaxLimits(el) {
  el.style.maxWidth = el.scrollWidth + 'px';
  el.style.maxHeight = el.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
ul {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(28 28 28 / 90%);
  width: min-content;
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / 70%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.reset {
  min-width: initial !important;
  min-height: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Добавить</button>
<button id="del">Удалить</button>
<ul>
  <li>Текст</li>
  <li>Текст</li>
</ul>
```

Можно поиграть активно кнопками, чтобы увидеть, как хорошо адаптируется анимация.
Ничего лучше придумать не смог, может еще кто-то поделится своим решением.

Comment: Что есть, сперва добавляем, затем удаляем и тд. Каждый раз абсолютно разные размеры. Как лучше быть, текущий пример работает только на увеличение размеров. Как быть, когда наоборот необходимо от больших привести к меньшим.

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов Обновил ответ, добавил удаление.